# Server sent events endpoint

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, server-sent-events

I am looking for a way to create a SSE for my application. What I want to do is create a sse that checks for when a user is created, also you must register to do this. So only people that are registred can get constant updates on new users through the sse feed.

Could anyone point me to the right direction on how to  approach this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's `SseEmitter`

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/users/validate")
public ResponseBodyEmitter userValidateEvent(){
     final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

     if(userService.validate(dummyUser)) {
         emitter.send("Some string" , MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
     }
     else {
         // log and return as per your requirement 
         return null;
     }
     emitter.complete();
     return emitter;
}
```